# MySql Group By the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

There is a "contacts" list. Some "contacts" are parents and some are children. Some contacts have more then one child. some children have more then one parent.
a contact can be a parent and a child (grand children).

The relationship between contacts is mapped in the table "parents_and_children".

```
"contacts" table
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | p1   |
|  2 | p2   |
|  3 | p3   |
|  4 | p4   |
|  5 | p5   |
|  6 | p6   |
+----+------+

"parents_and_children" table
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | parent_id | child_id |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |        2 |
|  2 |         1 |        3 |
|  3 |         3 |        4 |
|  4 |         5 |        2 |
|  5 |         5 |        3 |
|  6 |         5 |        6 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

The result of at query should be:

```
+-------------------+------------------+
| parent(s) name(s) | children name(s) |
+-------------------+------------------+
| p1, p5            | p2, p3           |
| p3                | p4               |
| p5                | p6               |
+-------------------+------------------+
```

Note that p3 is a child of p1 and p5 and also a parent to p4. p5 is a parent to p2 and p3 with p1, and p6 by himself.

I don't need the complete solution. Please show me the direction, and i will get there myself. So far, nothing worked.

Comment: MySQL does not have native support for recursion... which is why this question is widely discussed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` twice like this:

```
select pnames,
    group_concat(distinct cname order by cname separator ',') cnames
from (
    select group_concat(distinct c1.name order by c1.name separator ',') pnames,
        c2.name cname
    from parents_and_children p
    join contacts c1 on p.parent_id = c1.id
    join contacts c2 on p.child_id = c2.id
    group by c2.name
    ) t
group by pnames
```

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz - Where did I assume that?

Comment: I was not familiar enough with `group_concat` to downvote this ;) Would be good, if you could explain what the above query does.